# Больше чем int64

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Требуется как-то хранить числа больше чем int64 может содержать.

Есть идея создать массив int, где первый элемент - единицы, второй - тысячи, третий - миллионы и тд. Но это вариант решения очень громоздкий и занимает много места.

Какие ещё есть варианты или как улучшить предложенный?

Comment: Посмотрите BigInteger. Представляет произвольно большое целое число со знаком.

Comment: [тип decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/364x0z75(v=vs.120))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучший вариант - использовать [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx). Он может хранить любое, сколь угодно большое число.

Если нужно по каким-то причинам что-то самописное, изучить, как он устроен и изобрести велосипед :)

Вот описание:

https://habr.com/post/207754/

> Исследовав конструкторы структуры BigInteger можно заключить:
>       если число помещается в int диапазон, то оно хранится в переменной _sign;
>       если число не помещается в int диапазон, то его знак хранится в переменной _sign (-1 – для отрицательного и 1 – для положительного), а массив _bits содержит коэффициенты ai разложения длинного числа с основанием 2^32.

Answer (score 5):

Ваша идея правильная, с той только разницей что лучше хранить число не в десятичной системе счисления, а в системе с основанием 10<sup>9</sup> или 2<sup>32</sup> - это уменьшит потребление памяти в 9 раз.

Но если целью является не тренировка в алгоритмах длинной арифметики, а решение реальных задач - лучше использовать готовый класс BigInteger.

Comment: Уже хотел работать с BigInteger, но у меня отсутствует пространство имён System.Numerics? Может знаете что делать?

Comment: @Andrew добавить ссылку на сборку System.Numerics.dll

Comment: @Zergatul Спасибо. Попробую.